# jQuery datepicker: Getting the name of the previous month

Tags: jquery, date, picker

I'm using the jQuery datepicker plugin. I can get the current month using the code below. How can I get the name of the previous month?

```
 monthName = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM', $("#Calendar").datepicker('getDate'));
```

Please assist.

Comment: which month it is showing??

Comment: i m using inside this function                 $('#Calendar').datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function()
{
   var monthName = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM', $("#Calendar").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() - 1);
    alert(monthName);
})                                                                                                                                        i m getting this error -"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: @senthilkumar:- Did you try to use:- var $ =jQuery.noConflict(); to resolve the above error? Check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: i don't know how to use this can you give me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :-

```
monthName = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM', $("#Calendar").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() - 1);
```

OR-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Try this its working i have tried it myself :

Take a array as shown :-

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
           "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
```

and datepicker onSelect will look like this :-

```
$('#Calendar').datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function(dateText, inst) { var monthname = months[(dateText.split('/')[1]) - 2]; alert(monthname); })  //we have to subtract '2' instead of '1' because array `months` starts with index '0'.
```